# How to Read Document Template Xml Mapping value

Tags: c#, ms-word, office365, csom

I am using word document template, when I am upload document to document library in SharePoint online, column values are not set automatically.
I found that column mappings are broken that's why it is not setting column values.
I want read xml mappings column values using C# or any other way, it is possible to read xml mapping values?

I have tried to get XML node and try to extract from string, also tried to get from XML string.

Comment: Do you mean that users are setting the values of SharePoint properties (I.e. values of columns in the SharePoint library? but saving the document does not save the values? If so, is thism*template* a Word template (.dotx or .dotm), a SharePoint template (perhaps a .docx) or what. If you start with a file that has a different GUID for its metadata than the one SharePoint generates from a document library, I am pretty sure the values will not update, even if they have the same names as the library columns.

Answer (score 1):

Please use this code.

```
using System;
using System.Xml;

public class XmlMappingReader
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Load the XML file
        XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDoc.Load("path/to/your/xml/file.xml");

        // Select the mapping nodes
        XmlNodeList mappingNodes = xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//mapping");

        // Iterate over each mapping node
        foreach (XmlNode mappingNode in mappingNodes)
        {
            // Get the column attribute value
            string column = mappingNode.Attributes["column"].Value;

            // Get the value of the column
            string value = mappingNode.InnerText;

            // Do something with the column and value
            Console.WriteLine("Column: " + column);
            Console.WriteLine("Value: " + value);
        }
    }
}
```